# Shopify API: Get url that leads directly to checkout

Tags: javascript, rest, shopify

What options are there to forward people directly to a checkout page for a specific product in a Shopify store?

This is interesting for me for the following scenario:

1. User goes on my website where I talk about a product
2. Clicks a-href button
3. Gets directed to the checkout page (not product page) on my Shopify store

I have read the Product-sections on the API documentation but couldn't find a hint.

Comment: There are a lot of pre-made templates out there that offer that functionality so I'm guessing it is possible - could you not just make a little form with hidden quantity and product id fields and then style a button like your link so when you click on it it actually submits your product info to your checkout / basket page

Comment: Worked like a charm! Hope this will help others looking for an answer!

Answer (score 1):

This has been easier than anticipated!

(And it also helps at dealing with product variants)

Here is my Code(a simple Form):

```
<form method="post" action="{{ Shopify store url }}/cart/add" id="product_form_597803827251" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="product-form product-form-product-template
" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="product"><input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓">


  <select name="id" id="ProductSelect-product-template" class="product-form__variants no-js">


        <option selected="selected" value="7619582230579">
          Default Title
        </option>


  </select>


  <div class="product-form__item product-form__item--submit product-form__item--no-variants">
    <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart-product-template" class="btn product-form__cart-submit">
      <span id="AddToCartText-product-template">

          In den Einkaufswagen legen

      </span>
    </button>

  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better, Shopify lets you present buttons that use Apple Pay or Paypal for example, to skip cart and checkout and just process the order with the customer's favourite payment on their mobile.

Comment: Hi David, sounds awesome. Do you have a link with more info for me? Found only this: https://www.shopify.com/apple-pay